# Facebook sharer and parameters in url

Tags: facebook, wordpress, url

I have a Wordpress page that needs a GET parameter in URL.
Depending on the id, it shows a different flipbook.

The problem is, when I share the link on Facebook, it crops the GET parameters (I checked with the Open Graph Debugger), so the page doesn't receive any parameter, thus there's no thumb showed.
**I already tried encoding the URL with PHP.**

So, two questions:

1. Is it possible to make Facebook recognize the GET parameters in URL?
2. If not, can I work out something with the .htaccess file, to make them appear like subpages? E.g. `www.page.com/flipbook/?id=7` would become `www.page.com/flipbook/7/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was SEO Yoast was automatically writing the tag:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="www.page.com/flipbook/">
```

So Facebook was reading this and not the parameter.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer... what was the problem?